# Statiscal treatment of multiparticle system (Thermodynamics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

If a system of two energy levels with energies $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ is populated N particles at temperature T. The degeneracy of both levels is one. The particles populate the microstates to Boltzmann statistics. Then, what would be the average energy per particle?

Answer (score 1):

For a system of N particles where Nj particles occupy energy level ϵj, it should be easy to see that each set of Nj particles will have a total energy given by
$$N_j\epsilon_j $$
The total for the system would then be the sum of all of the sets, or
$$\sum_jN_j\epsilon_j$$
Using the definition of an average, it should be clear how to proceed from there.